# How to save webhooks page data to Salesforce custom object?

Tags: rest-api, integration, apexrest, webhooks, zap-scanner

In my requirement my webhook url having some data. when i am updating or inserting some data in my webhook page i want to save those data automatically in salesforce custom objects.
Is there a way to get Webhook updated/inserted data to Salesforce? how to integrate webhook to salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

You can check Zapier.com this will be to consume Response

Salesforce + Webhooks Integrations | Zapier

If you use webhooks that capture client contact information, Zapier can automatically add that information to Salesforce for you. Once the webhook is activated, Zapier will automatically extract the necessary information from the webhook and add it to Salesforce as a lead.

Comment: how to map my webhook url data in zapier catch hook ?